# An Excel user-defined function to read CSV files?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am looking for a VBA user-defined function that will read in the contents of a .csv file and return the results as an array to populate the cells of a worksheet, i.e something like this:

```
   =CSV_Read("path/to/file.csv")
```

I have found [this](http://www.oraxcel.com/projects/litlib/help/csv.html) but looks proprietary/shareware. Does anyone know of any alternatives? Or what the best approach to rolling my own in VBA would be?

Comment: CSV files as the name suggests should be comma seperated, Excel is more than capable of handling these with the Import Wizard, why do you need the VBA procedure?

Comment: Beacuse it's far less elegant than a function which can directly read the content in and can be refreshed with a simple shift-f9

Comment: @Richard the 'External Data' toolbar has a refresh button which re-imports the data from the wizard.

Comment: To add on to JP, you can even have it refresh on workbook open and even append if you require.  That gives you a datasource you can do anything with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your VBA code, add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".
Add a module, paste the following code.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function CSV_Read(ByVal path As String) As Variant
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim tsm As Scripting.TextStream

Dim data

Dim text As String
Dim allRowsInArray As Variant
Dim currentLineToArray As Variant

Dim columnCount As Integer
Dim columnCounter As Integer

Dim rowCounter As Integer
Dim rowCount As Integer

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set tsm = fso.OpenTextFile(path, ForReading)

rowCounter = 0
If Not tsm.AtEndOfStream Then
    text = tsm.ReadAll

    tsm.Close
    Set tsm = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    allRowsInArray = Split(text, vbCrLf)
    rowCount = UBound(allRowsInArray)

    Do While rowCounter < (rowCount + 1)
        currentLineToArray = Split(allRowsInArray(rowCounter), ",")

        If Not IsArray(data) Then
            columnCount = UBound(currentLineToArray)
            ReDim data(rowCount, columnCount)
        End If

        For columnCounter = 0 To columnCount
            data(rowCounter, columnCounter) = currentLineToArray(columnCounter)
        Next

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Loop
End If

CSV_Read = data
End Function
```

Sample CSV file data

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
7,6,5,4,3,2,1
q,w,e,r,t,y,u
```

Looking at the data, it has 7 columns and 4 rows.

Now, goto cell A1 and **select** the range from cell A1 to G4.
Type in the formula (`=CSV_Read("the full path to your csv file")`, in cell A1 (keeping the selection as it is).

**Important:**
Press <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER</kbd>, once you have finished typing in the formula. This is array formula.

Comment: That looks awesome thanks. But I'll have to amend the line splitting to cope with values that have commas in them.

Comment: @RichardH: Sure. I guess it might have some bugs, which I didnt think enough on. I hope it is directly usable in the code, with array formula.

Comment: This method presupposes you know the size of the txt file before import

Comment: @brettdj: Can you explain (presuppose the size of the text file), by an example?

Comment: +1 Having since seen the example that Richard H referred to I think my comment is less relevant - if the excel array is too big then extra results will simply error out in the "spare" cells. I did have to make a minor change on my testing `rowCount = UBound(allRowsInArray) - 1` to get the code working for my test. One suggestion - how about an optional user offset so the data pull cam be moved from the top left record. But very nice job - good stuff